# Написание Fizz and Buzz без цикла

Tags: python

Мне задали задачу написания Fizz and Buzz без цикла!
Я не понимаю как это?
И гуглил и спрашивал на других сайтах.
Ничего)))
Будте добры помогите)

Comment: используйте `map(..., range(...))`

Comment: @retorta, хм, внутри у них тот же цикл.

Comment: Повторяющиеся действия по определению цикл, будь это прыжок по метке с условием или `for`. Нужно ограничить конструкции языка, не иначе.

Comment: @Other Ну тут уж вопрос что нельзя использовать: если традиционные операторы цикла (for-while-...), то  вполне подходит. А избавиться от повторяющихся действий не выйдет. (Ну рекурсию можно  тут придумать ещё)

Comment: @retorta, рекурсия - тоже в каком-то смысле цикл :) Нужно определение от ТС.

Comment: @Other, без цикла (в вашем понимании - будь то `map`, рекурсия или какой-то внутренний метод/функция реализованная на `C`/'Cython', но использующая цикл во внутренней реализации) эту задачу не решить

Comment: @MaxU, благодарю, кэп. Поэтому и сказал чтобы уточнили какие именно конструкции запрещены.

Answer (score 0):

Решение рекурсивной функцией:

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    fizzbuzz(n - 1)
    if n % 3 == 0:
        print('Fizz', end='')
    if n % 5 == 0:
        print('Buzz', end='')
    if n % 3 and n % 5:
        print(n, end='')
    print('')


fizzbuzz(100)
```

https://repl.it/NA0u/0

Решение списковым включением:

```
print("\n".join([("Fizz"*(not i%3)+"Buzz"*(not i%5)+str(i)*(i%3!=0 and i%5!=0)) for i in range(1,101)]))
```

https://repl.it/NA0n/0

И вариант из ответа @MaxU, но без объявления отдельной функции:

```
print('\n'.join(map(lambda n: "FizzBuzz" if n % 15 == 0 else "Fizz" if n % 3 == 0 else "Buzz" if n % 5 == 0 else str(n), range(1, 101))))
```

https://repl.it/NA2P/0